# Graphviz---how do I make edges not cross each other; choose self-loop edge position

Tags: graphviz

I have the following dotfile:

```
digraph finite_state_machine {                                                                                                                                                                                  
    pad=0.2;
    {
        rank=same;
        node [shape = doublecircle]; q_3;
        node [shape = circle];
        q_1 [ label = <<b><i>q<sub>1</sub></i></b>> ];
        q_2 [ label = <<b><i>q<sub>2</sub></i></b>> ];
        q_3 [ label = <<b><i>q<sub>3</sub></i></b>> ];
        q_1 -> q_1 [ label = <<b><i>^a</i></b>> ];
        q_1 -> q_2 [ label = <<b><i>a</i></b>> ];
        q_2 -> q_2 [ label = <<b><i>^b</i></b>> ];
        q_2 -> q_3 [ label = <<b><i>b</i></b>> ];
    }
}
```

And I get the following output: [image: output image]

I want the self loops to be on top of the nodes, and not cross the other edges. And, if possible, more loopy loops. How can I achieve that?

I want it to look something like this: [image]

Answer (score 17):

You may use [ports/compass points](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#k:portPos):

```
q_1:e -> q_1:w [ label = <<b><i>^a</i></b>> ];
q_2:e -> q_2:w [ label = <<b><i>^b</i></b>> ];
```

[image: graphviz with loopy loops]

or using `nw`/`ne` as compass points:

[image: Event loopier loops]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I do not like the result. Edited my post to include a picture of what I want. Or maybe I can use ne and nw as directions/points. I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: Of course you can use nw/ne as compass points, I added a modified example